# PIX Call that Previously Succeeded Failed During Playback error on IASetVertexBuffers()

Tags: directx, hlsl, slimdx, vertex-buffer, pix

I'm trying to debug the shaders in a SlimDX DirectX11 game I've been coding for a while. The code runs fine and executes without a hitch (albeit seemingly ignoring my textures) and when I run an experiment to capture a single frame inside PIX it executes fine, however if I try to access either the Render or Mesh tabs in PIX for my captured frame I get the following error:

```
A call that previously succeeded failed during playback:

EID: 96
Call: ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers()
HRESULT: E_FAIL
```

The EID is one that occurs just before the frame I've captured (my frame starts at EID 108) so I can't see where it's failing.

I decided to run a full stream of frames to see if that would show me the error. This time I got something useful.

```
A call that previously succeeded failed during playback:

EID: 15
Call: IDXGISwapChain::GetParent()
HRESULT:E_FAIL
```

And the event log that caused it:

```
Frame 1 EID
Call    4   D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, 7, 0x0016EE7C, 0x0016EE74 --> 0x07145B60, 0x0016EE6C --> 0x071453B0, NULL, 0x0016EE70 --> 0x071BA108)
Call    5   CreateObject(D3D11 Device, 0x071453B0)
Call    6   CreateObject(DXGI Factory, 0x07145A58)
Call    7   CreateObject(DXGI Adapter, 0x07145AA8)
Call    8   CreateObject(DXGI Device, 0x07145B00)
Call    9   CreateObject(DXGI Swap Chain, 0x07145B60)
Call    10  CreateObject(DXGI Surface, 0x07145BF8)
Call    11  CreateObject(D3D11 Texture2D, 0x07145C58)
Call    12  CreateObject(D3D11 Device Context, 0x071BA108)
Call    13  <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::Release()
Call    14  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::GetImmediateContext(0x071BA108 --> 0x6C54A8D8)
Call    15  <0x07145B60> IDXGISwapChain::GetParent(IID_IDXGIFactory, 0x0016EF40 --> 0x07145A58)
Call    16  <0x07145A58> IDXGIFactory::MakeWindowAssociation(0x00020574, 2)
Call    17  <0x07145A58> IDXGIFactory::Release()
Call    18  <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::RSSetViewports(1, 0x0016EF28)
Call    19  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D(0x0016EDCC, NULL, 0x0016EDC8 --> 0x071460F8)
Call    20  CreateObject(D3D11 Texture2D, 0x071460F8)
Call    21  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateDepthStencilView(0x071460F8, 0x0016EE2C, 0x0016EE4C --> 0x07146198)
Call    22  CreateObject(D3D11 Depth-Stencil View, 0x07146198)
Call    23  <0x071460F8> ID3D11Texture2D::Release()
Call    24  <0x07145B60> IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer(0, IID_ID3D11Texture2D, 0x0016EF3C --> 0x07145C58)
Call    25  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateRenderTargetView(0x07145C58, NULL, 0x0016EF40 --> 0x071461F0)
Call    26  CreateObject(D3D11 Render Target View, 0x071461F0)
Call    27  <0x07145C58> ID3D11Texture2D::Release()
Call    28  <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets(1, 0x0016EF54 --> { 0x071461F0 }, 0x07146198)
Call    29  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader(0x00A90FA0, 1116, NULL, 0x0016EF24 --> 0x071462F8)
Call    30  CreateObject(D3D11 Vertex Shader, 0x071462F8)
Call    31  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreatePixelShader(0x00A8FC00, 1160, NULL, 0x0016EF24 --> 0x071467B8)
Call    32  CreateObject(D3D11 Pixel Shader, 0x071467B8)
Call    33  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader(0x00A92348, 568, NULL, 0x0016EF24 --> 0x07146CA0)
Call    34  CreateObject(D3D11 Vertex Shader, 0x07146CA0)
Call    35  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreatePixelShader(0x00ABE3F8, 8232, NULL, 0x0016EF24 --> 0x07146F38)
Call    36  CreateObject(D3D11 Pixel Shader, 0x07146F38)
Call    37  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader(0x00A92548, 568, NULL, 0x0016EF24 --> 0x07146F90)
Call    38  CreateObject(D3D11 Vertex Shader, 0x07146F90)
Call    39  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreatePixelShader(0x00B117C0, 1756, NULL, 0x0016EF24 --> 0x07139848)
Call    40  CreateObject(D3D11 Pixel Shader, 0x07139848)
Call    41  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader(0x00A925D8, 568, NULL, 0x0016EF24 --> 0x071454A0)
Call    42  CreateObject(D3D11 Vertex Shader, 0x071454A0)
Call    43  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreatePixelShader(0x00ABE018, 7196, NULL, 0x0016EF24 --> 0x07145738)
Call    44  CreateObject(D3D11 Pixel Shader, 0x07145738)
Call    45  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::AddRef()
Call    46  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D(0x0016EE08, 0x00A90768, 0x0016EE04 --> 0x07145790)
Call    47  CreateObject(D3D11 Texture2D, 0x07145790)
Call    48  <0x07145790> ID3D11Texture2D::GetType(0x0016EDB4)
Call    49  <0x07145790> ID3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface(IID_ID3D11Texture2D, 0x0016EDD8 --> 0x07145790)
Call    50  <0x07145790> ID3D11Texture2D::GetDesc(0x0016EE24)
Call    51  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateShaderResourceView(0x07145790, 0x0016EDBC, 0x0016EF44 --> 0x07145830)
Call    52  CreateObject(D3D11 Shader Resource View, 0x07145830)
Call    53  <0x07145790> ID3D11Texture2D::Release()
Call    54  <0x07145790> ID3D11Texture2D::Release()
Call    55  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::Release()
Call    56  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::AddRef()
Call    57  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D(0x0016EE08, 0x00A8F6A0, 0x0016EE04 --> 0x0713A990)
Call    58  CreateObject(D3D11 Texture2D, 0x0713A990)
Call    59  <0x0713A990> ID3D11Texture2D::GetType(0x0016EDB4)
Call    60  <0x0713A990> ID3D11Texture2D::QueryInterface(IID_ID3D11Texture2D, 0x0016EDD8 --> 0x0713A990)
Call    61  <0x0713A990> ID3D11Texture2D::GetDesc(0x0016EE24)
Call    62  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateShaderResourceView(0x0713A990, 0x0016EDBC, 0x0016EF44 --> 0x071C3B98)
Call    63  CreateObject(D3D11 Shader Resource View, 0x071C3B98)
Call    64  <0x0713A990> ID3D11Texture2D::Release()
Call    65  <0x0713A990> ID3D11Texture2D::Release()
Call    66  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::Release()
Call    67  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateSamplerState(0x0016EED4, 0x0016EED0 --> 0x07145938)
Call    68  CreateObject(D3D11 Sampler State, 0x07145938)
Call    69  <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, 0x0016EF38 --> { 0x07145830 })
Call    70  <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(4, 1, 0x0016EF38 --> { 0x071C3B98 })
Call    71  <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetSamplers(0, 1, 0x0016EF38 --> { 0x07145938 })
Call    72  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0016EDF4, 0x0016EDDC, 0x0016EDF0 --> 0x0713AA30)
Call    73  CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x0713AA30)
Call    74  <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016EE68 --> { 0x0713AA30 })
Call    75  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D(0x0016ECD0, NULL, 0x0016ECCC --> 0x0713AAB8)
Call    76  CreateObject(D3D11 Texture2D, 0x0713AAB8)
Call    77  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateRenderTargetView(0x0713AAB8, 0x0016ED28, 0x0016ED44 --> 0x071C3BF0)
Call    78  CreateObject(D3D11 Render Target View, 0x071C3BF0)
Call    79  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateShaderResourceView(0x0713AAB8, 0x0016ECF4, 0x0016ED14 --> 0x071C3C48)
Call    80  CreateObject(D3D11 Shader Resource View, 0x071C3C48)
Call    81  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D(0x0016ECD0, NULL, 0x0016ECCC --> 0x0713AB58)
Call    82  CreateObject(D3D11 Texture2D, 0x0713AB58)
Call    83  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateRenderTargetView(0x0713AB58, 0x0016ED28, 0x0016ED44 --> 0x071C3CA0)
Call    84  CreateObject(D3D11 Render Target View, 0x071C3CA0)
Call    85  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateShaderResourceView(0x0713AB58, 0x0016ECF4, 0x0016ED14 --> 0x071C3CF8)
Call    86  CreateObject(D3D11 Shader Resource View, 0x071C3CF8)
Call    87  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D(0x0016ECD0, NULL, 0x0016ECCC --> 0x0713ACA8)
Call    88  CreateObject(D3D11 Texture2D, 0x0713ACA8)
Call    89  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateRenderTargetView(0x0713ACA8, 0x0016ED28, 0x0016ED44 --> 0x071C3D50)
Call    90  CreateObject(D3D11 Render Target View, 0x071C3D50)
Call    91  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateShaderResourceView(0x0713ACA8, 0x0016ECF4, 0x0016ED14 --> 0x071C3DA8)
Call    92  CreateObject(D3D11 Shader Resource View, 0x071C3DA8)
Call    93  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D(0x0016ECD0, NULL, 0x0016ECCC --> 0x0713AD48)
Call    94  CreateObject(D3D11 Texture2D, 0x0713AD48)
Call    95  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateRenderTargetView(0x0713AD48, 0x0016ED28, 0x0016ED44 --> 0x071C3E00)
Call    96  CreateObject(D3D11 Render Target View, 0x071C3E00)
Call    97  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateShaderResourceView(0x0713AD48, 0x0016ECF4, 0x0016ED14 --> 0x071C3E58)
Call    98  CreateObject(D3D11 Shader Resource View, 0x071C3E58)
Call    99  <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D(0x0016ED00, NULL, 0x0016ECFC --> 0x0713ADE8)
Call    100 CreateObject(D3D11 Texture2D, 0x0713ADE8)
Call    101 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateRenderTargetView(0x0713ADE8, 0x0016ED58, 0x0016ED74 --> 0x071C3EB0)
Call    102 CreateObject(D3D11 Render Target View, 0x071C3EB0)
Call    103 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateShaderResourceView(0x0713ADE8, 0x0016ED24, 0x0016ED44 --> 0x071C3F08)
Call    104 CreateObject(D3D11 Shader Resource View, 0x071C3F08)
Call    105 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateTexture2D(0x0016ED00, NULL, 0x0016ECFC --> 0x0713AE88)
Call    106 CreateObject(D3D11 Texture2D, 0x0713AE88)
Call    107 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateRenderTargetView(0x0713AE88, 0x0016ED58, 0x0016ED74 --> 0x071C3F60)
Call    108 CreateObject(D3D11 Render Target View, 0x071C3F60)
Call    109 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateShaderResourceView(0x0713AE88, 0x0016ED24, 0x0016ED44 --> 0x071C3FB8)
Call    110 CreateObject(D3D11 Shader Resource View, 0x071C3FB8)
Call    111 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateInputLayout(0x0016EC64, 3, 0x066B15E8, 152, 0x0016EC5C --> 0x0713AFD8)
Call    112 CreateObject(D3D11 Input Layout, 0x0713AFD8)
Call    113 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetInputLayout(0x0713AFD8)
Call    114 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST)
Call    115 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0016EDC0, 0x0016EDA8, 0x0016EDBC --> 0x0713B0C0)
Call    116 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x0713B0C0)
Call    117 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::GetImmediateContext(0x071BA108 --> 0x6C54A8D8)
Call    118 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::Release()
Call    119 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016EE34 --> { 0x0713B0C0 })
Call    120 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::GetImmediateContext(0x071BA108 --> 0x6C54A8D8)
Call    121 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::Release()
Call    122 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::UpdateSubresource(0x0713B0C0, 0, NULL, 0x066B1928, 0, 0)
Call    123 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0016EC4C, 0x0016EC34, 0x0016EC48 --> 0x0713B148)
Call    124 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x0713B148)
Call    125 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0016EC4C, 0x0016EC34, 0x0016EC48 --> 0x0713B1D0)
Call    126 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x0713B1D0)
Call    127 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0FDCE878, 0x0FDCE860, 0x0FDCE874 --> 0x0713A120)
Call    128 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x0713A120)
Call    129 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0FDCE878, 0x0FDCE860, 0x0FDCE874 --> 0x0713A1A8)
Call    130 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x0713A1A8)
Call    131 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0FB9EFE8, 0x0FB9EFD0, 0x0FB9EFE4 --> 0x0713B258)
Call    132 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x0713B258)
Call    133 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0FB9EFE8, 0x0FB9EFD0, 0x0FB9EFE4 --> 0x0713B2E0)
Call    134 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x0713B2E0)
Call    135 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0FDCE878, 0x0FDCE860, 0x0FDCE874 --> 0x071C65E8)
Call    136 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C65E8)
Call    137 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0FDCE878, 0x0FDCE860, 0x0FDCE874 --> 0x071C6670)
Call    138 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6670)
Call    139 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F49EEF8, 0x0F49EEE0, 0x0F49EEF4 --> 0x071C6710)
Call    140 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6710)
Call    141 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F49EEF8, 0x0F49EEE0, 0x0F49EEF4 --> 0x071C6798)
Call    142 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6798)
Call    143 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F7EED88, 0x0F7EED70, 0x0F7EED84 --> 0x071C6820)
Call    144 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6820)
Call    145 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F7EED88, 0x0F7EED70, 0x0F7EED84 --> 0x071C68A8)
Call    146 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C68A8)
Call    147 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F7EED88, 0x0F7EED70, 0x0F7EED84 --> 0x071C6930)
Call    148 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6930)
Call    149 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F7EED88, 0x0F7EED70, 0x0F7EED84 --> 0x071C69B8)
Call    150 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C69B8)
Call    151 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F63F038, 0x0F63F020, 0x0F63F034 --> 0x071C6A40)
Call    152 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6A40)
Call    153 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F63F038, 0x0F63F020, 0x0F63F034 --> 0x071C6AC8)
Call    154 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6AC8)
Call    155 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F49EEF8, 0x0F49EEE0, 0x0F49EEF4 --> 0x071C6B50)
Call    156 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6B50)
Call    157 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F49EEF8, 0x0F49EEE0, 0x0F49EEF4 --> 0x071C6BD8)
Call    158 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6BD8)
Call    159 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F63F038, 0x0F63F020, 0x0F63F034 --> 0x071C6C60)
Call    160 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6C60)
Call    161 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F63F038, 0x0F63F020, 0x0F63F034 --> 0x071C6CE8)
Call    162 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6CE8)
Call    163 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F7EED88, 0x0F7EED70, 0x0F7EED84 --> 0x071C6D70)
Call    164 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6D70)
Call    165 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F7EED88, 0x0F7EED70, 0x0F7EED84 --> 0x071C6DF8)
Call    166 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6DF8)
Call    167 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0FB9EFE8, 0x0FB9EFD0, 0x0FB9EFE4 --> 0x071C6E80)
Call    168 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6E80)
Call    169 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0FB9EFE8, 0x0FB9EFD0, 0x0FB9EFE4 --> 0x071C6F08)
Call    170 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6F08)
Call    171 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearRenderTargetView(0x071461F0, 0x0016EE5C)
Call    172 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearDepthStencilView(0x07146198, 1, 1.000f, 0)
Call    173 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0016EE04, 0x0016EDEC, 0x0016EE00 --> 0x071C6F90)
Call    174 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C6F90)
Call    175 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016EE78 --> { 0x071C6F90 })
Call    176 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::GetImmediateContext(0x071BA108 --> 0x6C54A8D8)
Call    177 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::Release()
Call    178 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::UpdateSubresource(0x0713B0C0, 0, NULL, 0x066B1928, 0, 0)
Call    179 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::VSSetShader(0x071462F8, NULL, 0)
Call    180 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShader(0x071467B8, NULL, 0)
Call    181 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateInputLayout(0x0016E9C4, 3, 0x066B15E8, 152, 0x0016E9BC --> 0x0713A230)
Call    182 CreateObject(D3D11 Input Layout, 0x0713A230)
Call    183 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetInputLayout(0x0713A230)
Call    184 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST)
Call    185 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::GetImmediateContext(0x071BA108 --> 0x6C54A8D8)
Call    186 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::Release()
Call    187 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016EE08 --> { 0x0713B0C0 })
Call    188 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(2, 1, 0x0016EE20 --> { NULL })
Call    189 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(3, 1, 0x0016EE20 --> { NULL })
Call    190 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(5, 1, 0x0016EE20 --> { NULL })
Call    191 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(6, 1, 0x0016EE20 --> { NULL })
Call    192 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets(4, 0x0016EDE8 --> { 0x071C3BF0, 0x071C3CA0, 0x071C3D50, 0x071C3E00 }, 0x07146198)
Call    193 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearRenderTargetView(0x071C3BF0, 0x0016EDD0)
Call    194 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearRenderTargetView(0x071C3CA0, 0x0016EDD0)
Call    195 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearRenderTargetView(0x071C3D50, 0x0016EDD0)
Call    196 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearRenderTargetView(0x071C3E00, 0x0016EDD0)
Call    197 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearDepthStencilView(0x07146198, 1, 1.000f, 0)
Call    198 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F49EEF8, 0x0F49EEE0, 0x0F49EEF4 --> 0x071C7018)
Call    199 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C7018)
Call    200 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F49EEF8, 0x0F49EEE0, 0x0F49EEF4 --> 0x071C70A0)
Call    201 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C70A0)
Call    202 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0FDCE878, 0x0FDCE860, 0x0FDCE874 --> 0x071C7128)
Call    203 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C7128)
Call    204 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0FDCE878, 0x0FDCE860, 0x0FDCE874 --> 0x071C71B0)
Call    205 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C71B0)
Call    206 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F63F038, 0x0F63F020, 0x0F63F034 --> 0x071C7238)
Call    207 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C7238)
Call    208 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0F63F038, 0x0F63F020, 0x0F63F034 --> 0x071C72C0)
Call    209 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C72C0)
Call    210 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0FA3EAB8, 0x0FA3EAA0, 0x0FA3EAB4 --> 0x071C7348)
Call    211 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C7348)
Call    212 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0FA3EAB8, 0x0FA3EAA0, 0x0FA3EAB4 --> 0x071C73D0)
Call    213 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C73D0)
Call    214 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016ED04 --> { 0x0713A120 }, 0x0016ED08, 0x0016ED0C)
Call    215 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer(0x0713A1A8, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0)
Call    216 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed(924, 0, 0)
Call    217 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016ED04 --> { 0x0713B258 }, 0x0016ED08, 0x0016ED0C)
Call    218 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer(0x0713B2E0, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0)
Call    219 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed(13692, 0, 0)
Call    220 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016ED04 --> { 0x071C65E8 }, 0x0016ED08, 0x0016ED0C)
Call    221 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer(0x071C6670, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0)
Call    222 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed(4044, 0, 0)
Call    223 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016ED04 --> { 0x071C6710 }, 0x0016ED08, 0x0016ED0C)
Call    224 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer(0x071C6798, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0)
Call    225 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed(28260, 0, 0)
Call    226 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016ED04 --> { 0x071C6820 }, 0x0016ED08, 0x0016ED0C)
Call    227 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer(0x071C68A8, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0)
Call    228 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed(1860, 0, 0)
Call    229 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016ED04 --> { 0x071C6930 }, 0x0016ED08, 0x0016ED0C)
Call    230 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer(0x071C69B8, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0)
Call    231 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0)
Call    232 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016ED04 --> { 0x071C6A40 }, 0x0016ED08, 0x0016ED0C)
Call    233 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer(0x071C6AC8, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0)
Call    234 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed(25584, 0, 0)
Call    235 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016ED04 --> { 0x071C6C60 }, 0x0016ED08, 0x0016ED0C)
Call    236 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer(0x071C6CE8, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0)
Call    237 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed(6816, 0, 0)
Call    238 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016ED04 --> { 0x071C6D70 }, 0x0016ED08, 0x0016ED0C)
Call    239 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer(0x071C6DF8, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0)
Call    240 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed(12528, 0, 0)
Call    241 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016ED04 --> { 0x071C6E80 }, 0x0016ED08, 0x0016ED0C)
Call    242 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer(0x071C6F08, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0)
Call    243 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed(3252, 0, 0)
Call    244 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0016EBF8, 0x0016EBE0, 0x0016EBF4 --> 0x071C7458)
Call    245 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C7458)
Call    246 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0016EBF8, 0x0016EBE0, 0x0016EBF4 --> 0x071C74E0)
Call    247 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C74E0)
Call    248 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::VSSetShader(0x07146CA0, NULL, 0)
Call    249 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShader(0x07146F38, NULL, 0)
Call    250 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateInputLayout(0x0016E958, 3, 0x066B18A8, 120, 0x0016E950 --> 0x071C4D40)
Call    251 CreateObject(D3D11 Input Layout, 0x071C4D40)
Call    252 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetInputLayout(0x071C4D40)
Call    253 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST)
Call    254 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(7, 1, 0x0016EDB4 --> { NULL })
Call    255 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets(1, 0x0016ED9C --> { 0x071C3EB0 }, 0x07146198)
Call    256 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearRenderTargetView(0x071C3EB0, 0x0016ED70)
Call    257 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearDepthStencilView(0x07146198, 1, 1.000f, 0)
Call    258 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(2, 1, 0x0016EDB4 --> { 0x071C3CF8 })
Call    259 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(3, 1, 0x0016EDB4 --> { 0x071C3DA8 })
Call    260 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016EDA0 --> { 0x071C7458 }, 0x0016EDA4, 0x0016EDA8)
Call    261 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer(0x071C74E0, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0)
Call    262 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed(6, 0, 0)
Call    263 <0x071C7458> ID3D11Buffer::Release()
Call    264 <0x071C74E0> ID3D11Buffer::Release()
Call    265 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0016EBF0, 0x0016EBD8, 0x0016EBEC --> 0x071C7568)
Call    266 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C7568)
Call    267 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0016EBF0, 0x0016EBD8, 0x0016EBEC --> 0x071C75F0)
Call    268 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C75F0)
Call    269 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::VSSetShader(0x07146F90, NULL, 0)
Call    270 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShader(0x07139848, NULL, 0)
Call    271 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateInputLayout(0x0016E950, 3, 0x065688E0, 120, 0x0016E948 --> 0x071C5600)
Call    272 CreateObject(D3D11 Input Layout, 0x071C5600)
Call    273 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetInputLayout(0x071C5600)
Call    274 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST)
Call    275 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(1, 1, 0x0016EDAC --> { NULL })
Call    276 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets(1, 0x0016ED94 --> { 0x071C3F60 }, 0x07146198)
Call    277 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearRenderTargetView(0x071C3F60, 0x0016ED68)
Call    278 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearDepthStencilView(0x07146198, 1, 1.000f, 0)
Call    279 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(5, 1, 0x0016EDAC --> { 0x071C3C48 })
Call    280 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(6, 1, 0x0016EDAC --> { 0x071C3E58 })
Call    281 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(7, 1, 0x0016EDAC --> { 0x071C3F08 })
Call    282 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016ED98 --> { 0x071C7568 }, 0x0016ED9C, 0x0016EDA0)
Call    283 DestroyObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C7458)
Call    284 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer(0x071C75F0, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0)
Call    285 DestroyObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C74E0)
Call    286 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed(6, 0, 0)
Call    287 <0x071C7568> ID3D11Buffer::Release()
Call    288 <0x071C75F0> ID3D11Buffer::Release()
Call    289 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0016EC00, 0x0016EBE8, 0x0016EBFC --> 0x071C7678)
Call    290 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C7678)
Call    291 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer(0x0016EC00, 0x0016EBE8, 0x0016EBFC --> 0x071C7700)
Call    292 CreateObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C7700)
Call    293 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::VSSetShader(0x071454A0, NULL, 0)
Call    294 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShader(0x07145738, NULL, 0)
Call    295 <0x071453B0> ID3D11Device::CreateInputLayout(0x0016E960, 3, 0x06568960, 120, 0x0016E958 --> 0x071C56C0)
Call    296 CreateObject(D3D11 Input Layout, 0x071C56C0)
Call    297 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetInputLayout(0x071C56C0)
Call    298 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST)
Call    299 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets(1, 0x0016EDBC --> { 0x071461F0 }, 0x07146198)
Call    300 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearRenderTargetView(0x071461F0, 0x0016EDA0)
Call    301 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearDepthStencilView(0x07146198, 1, 1.000f, 0)
Call    302 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetShaderResources(1, 1, 0x0016EDBC --> { 0x071C3FB8 })
Call    303 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, 0x0016EDA8 --> { 0x071C7678 }, 0x0016EDAC, 0x0016EDB0)
Call    304 DestroyObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C7568)
Call    305 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetIndexBuffer(0x071C7700, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0)
Call    306 DestroyObject(D3D11 Buffer, 0x071C75F0)
Call    307 <0x071BA108> ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexed(6, 0, 0)
Call    308 <0x071C7678> ID3D11Buffer::Release()
Call    309 <0x071C7700> ID3D11Buffer::Release()
Call    310 <0x07145B60> IDXGISwapChain::Present(0, 0)
Frame   311 Frame 2
```

There's nothing in the output log either. Has anybody encountered this before? If so how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the reply may not be needed any longer or may differ from the cause of your problem, I at least was troubled by the IASetVertexBuffers() error problem of PIX similar to it.

The cause in my case was having disposed of the buffer which remains bound as a Vertex buffer.

The error has been avoided when the original buffer was disposed of after it, after binding null to the Vertex buffer.

```
// Create Buffer
buffer = new SlimDX.Direct3D11.Buffer(device, stream, vertexBufferDesc);
stream.Dispose();

// Bind
device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(buffer, stride, 0));

// Draw
effectPass.Apply(device.ImmediateContext);
device.ImmediateContext.Draw(primitiveCount, 0);

// Unbind and Dispose
device.ImmediateContext.InputAssembler.SetVertexBuffers(0, new VertexBufferBinding(null, 0, 0)); 
buffer.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered those errors before, whenever I was using stream output with the vertex shader (not sure if with geometry shader also). There was no fix for it.

Depending on what GPU you have, try debugging your application with AMDs GPU PerfStudio or Nvidias Parallel Nsight. Maybe it will work in them.